# How do I get device token information from all my users for push notifications?

Tags: iphone, push-notification

I don't see how http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH1-SW1 tells me how to get device tokens for Push. I've read a couple of books, but they are of no help.

I want to develop my own system to keep track of them via feedback and via a dictionary. I want to send broadcast messages.

To be clear, **I want to get the device tokens from my users' devices to my Push server.**

I feel I am missing something obvious. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

When the user accepts push notification the `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:` method will be called with an NSData object with the info:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)devToken {
       devToken = ...
}
```

Comment: But how do I get this info to the Push server?

Comment: In that method, call back to your server with the info and insert it into a database.

Answer (score 0):

The app is responsible for sending it to your Push Server. You have to define your own method to do this, e.g. HTTP POST or some other proprietary protocol.

For example, Urban Airship's iOS library makes an HTTP request to its server. See the `registerDeviceTokenWithExtraInfo` method in the [UAirship.m](https://github.com/urbanairship/ios-library/blob/master/Airship/Library/AirshipLib/UAirship.m) file.